# java- how can you set the Look&Feel to JOptionPanes and classes that extend JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jdialog, joptionpane

I'm currently using Look&Feel for my application. I have a few problems:

**1.** When I start my program, the first thing that pops up is a JDialog for login. This is normal, but the problem is that it's the default Look&Feel. Now, after you get pass the login, the main program launches with the Look&Feel I chose. One thing to note is that the JDialog is constructed like this:

```
    public class FooLogin extends JDialog{
        // variables...

    public FooLogin(JFrame parent){
        // code...
```

**2.** My JOptionPanes are all default as well.

So how do I explicitly apply Look&Feel to a JDialog in this form?
And how can I match the JOptionPanes to the Look&Feel of the main program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to mentioned for which from `Look and Feels`, but by default you have to read [Changing the Look and Feel After Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic), then you have to call code line before visible of a new Container

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

be sure that you have to create a new Container wrapped into `invokeLater`, more in [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: sorry about that. I'm using Nimbus for my L&F